# ul not aligning properly in div

Tags: html, css

I have a nav next to a div. Nav is floated left. Then I have a ul in the div.

All of the bullets for the ul are so far left that they are in the nav section.

The text of the li items is aligned with paragraph text instead of the bullets being aligned with the paragraph text.

How do I make the ul align as it normally would?

```css
.toc {
float:left;
width:100px;
}
.content {
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<nav class="toc">
<ol>
  <li>section 1
  <li>section 2
  <li>section 3
  <li>section 4  
  <li>section 5
 </ol>
 </nav>
<div class="content">
<p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
<ul>
  <li>item 1 
  <li>item 1  
  <li>item 1  
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is with the indentation on those lis?

Comment: Indentation is irrelevant. Why aren’t you closing your tags? `<li></li>`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.toc {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
p{
margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="toc">
  <ol>
    <li>section 1
    <li>section 2
    <li>section 3
    <li>section 4  
    <li>section 5
   </ol>
 </nav>
<div class="content">
<p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
  <ul>
      <li>item 1 
      <li>item 1  
      <li>item 1  
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of bullets/numberings - they appear to the left of normal paragraph flow. To align them with the text you need to do it yourself. The easiest way to do it is to use `li { margin-left: 1em }`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of float add display inline-block to your classes.

```
.toc {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: If I add inline-block to both it doesn't fix the bullet problem. And it wraps the div so that it starts after the nav instead of next to it.

Comment: Well, it actually works on the example html I pasted above, but I can't get it to work on the larger page I'm actually writing. So... something's up there. Guess I have a new problem to solve.

Comment: Ahhh. As long as the text in the p was short enough that it didn't have to wrap, all was as expected. The nav was left of the div and the bullets were indented properly. But as soon as I add a few more sentences of text to the p, to the point where it has to wrap, the div is positioned below the nav instead of the right of it. Any ideas? And thanks for the 1st. I feel like I'm closer.

Comment: If I set the width of the div to calc(100% - 100px) then it displays the nav to the left & the div to the right and the bullets are indented properly. So that's a fix, in a way. But I don't want this to be the width of the div all the way down. It's a very long page & the nav is much shorter. After the nav, I want the div to go back to 100% width. I feel like it just shouldn't be the hard. Haha.

Comment: Question has changed :D @user3875333

Comment: Yes. I just thought you might have a quick comment since you were already familiar. Thanks for your help. I can probably figure it out from here.